# Conversion from decimal to binary in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int  n, p, s;
    printf("input n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    p=0;
    while(n!=0){
        s += (n%2)*pow(10, p);
        p+=1;
        n/=2;
    }
    printf("%d", s);

}
```

I am newbie and i don't know why my code outputs wrong values. May you help me find the mistake in my code?

Comment: Can you add the output of your code when executed with some test inputs? Also, what is your goal here? Do you want to read a number as binary or print it in binary form? because your code does neither

Comment: What are you entering? A decimal number that is pretending to be a binary by  consisting of only `0` and `1` digits? If so, just input a string and print it. But if you want true decimal to binary, that conversion has already been done by `scanf`. So you need to be working with `2` not with `10`, to get binary back out.

Comment: By using `scanf("%d", &n)` to input the number, it is automatically converted to binary form, in the sense that the user types some digits (ASCII characters, string) and you get the value in `n` which is an `int`, 4 bytes (depending on platform) which is actually 4 x 8 =32 bits binary. However,if you want to print the binary digits (1 and 0) that result from this conversion, then you need to store them in a `char` array as you extract them from `n`. So,what do you want to do?

Comment: s is used not initialized

Comment: Note that `s += (n%2)*pow(10, p);` is confused as to whether it is doing a binary or a decimal conversion. It suggests that each *bit* represents either `0` or `10`.

Comment: You should do the conversion using the `<<` and the `&`operators. Your program (poorly) converts from decimal numbers to decimal numbers pretending to be binary (consisting only of 1s and 0s..

Comment: Also, you will only be able to input a "10-bit number" to `int` before it overflows. The "11-bit number" `10000000000` is greater than 2^32.

Answer (score 1):

Just initialise variable `s` to 0.

Also, for a 32 bit integer, to avoid integer overflow due to `pow()` use the following method:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void decToBinary(int n) 
{ 
    // array to store binary number 
    int binaryNum[32]; 

    // counter for binary array 
    int i = 0; 
    while (n > 0) { 

        // storing remainder in binary array 
        binaryNum[i] = n % 2; 
        n = n / 2; 
        i++; 
    } 

    // printing binary array in reverse orader 
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
        printf("%d",binaryNum[j]); 
} 

// Driver program to test above function 
int main() 
{ 
    int n = 10; 
    decToBinary(n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Using bitshift and masking would be a better alternative.

Comment: You need to first initialise binaryNum into an array of 0's using memset otherwise you will get strange values for the locations that where not initialised.